# General formula for natural power summation

Tags: reference-request, proof-explanation, arithmetic-progressions

Where can I find the formula for $$\sum n^k$$ and subsequently the formula for 
$$\sum (a+(n-1)d)^k$$

for $k \in N$
along with corresponding proofs.

Comment: have you tried google?

Comment: @NL628 I found this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Summae_Potestatum

but not containing the prerequisite terminology needed

Answer (score 2):

According to your Wikipedia article in the comments,

> A rigorous proof of these formulas and his assertion that such
>   formulas would exist for all odd powers took until Carl Jacobi (1834).

So we only have a guaranteed formula for odd powers. But, if you wanted to know, Mathworld also has a not-so-concise form that holds for all odd powers:

\begin{align}
 1^{p} + 2^{p} &+ 3^{p} + \cdots + n^{p}\\ &= \frac{1}{p+1} \sum_{i=1}^{p+1} (-1)^{\delta_{i\space p}} \binom{p+1}{i}
B_{p+1-i}n^i.
\end{align}

where $B_i$ is the $i$th Bernoulli number.

*The reason there is no concise formula is because if you notice the coefficients for most of the formulas are very different, so the general formula must contain some way to generate these coefficients.*

Comment: For even powers and arithmetic power?

Comment: @hanugm 
According to the Wikipedia article, there is no proof that such formulas exist for even powers, so there is no general formula. is this answer okay? do you have any other questions on this topic?

Comment: "no proof that such formulas exist for even powers" and "there is no general formula" where such statement are?

Comment: please refer some research paper or article stating that

Comment: @hanugm does this work? there is a formula for ALL powers, but it isn't very concise...

Answer (score 0):

there are many, I'll post some

**[1-Using derivatives]**

$$s(n) = \sum^{n}_{k=0} k^p =\sum^{p+1}_{k=1}a_k n^k   $$

where
$$ a_{t+1} =\frac{1}{t+1}\sum^{p+1}_{k=t+2}a_k{ k  \choose t} (-1)^{k-t}\;\; ,\;\; a_{p+1}=\frac{1}{p+1}. $$

**Proof:**

From $s(n) = \sum\limits^{n}_{k=0} k^p $, then $s(n) -s(n-1)=n^p $.
Let's suppose
  $s(n)= \sum\limits^{p+1}_{k=1}a_k n^k $
which has the independent term $a_0=0$ because $s(0) =0$.
We apply the $p$-th derivative in $s(n) -s(n-1)=n^p $ which results in
$$s^{(p)}(n) -s^{(p)}(n-1) =p! $$
 we have $s^{(p)}(n) = a_p.p! + a_{p+1}(p+1)!n$ so  $s^{(p)}(n) -s^{(p)}(n-1) (n)=a_{p+1}(p+1)!=p! $ which implies  $a_{p+1}=\frac{1}{(p+1)} .$

We will find the other coefficients. We take the $t$-th derivative in $s(n) -s(n-1)=n^p$, with $0 \leq t<p$, so
$$s^{(t)}(n) -s^{(t)}(n-1) =t!{p \choose t} n^{p-t} $$, taking $n=0$ we have
$$s^{(t)}(0) =s^{t}(-1)  $$

Using $s(n)= \sum\limits^{p+1}_{k=1}a_k x^k $ and applying again the $t$-th derivative
$$ s^{(t)} (n)= \sum^{p+1}_{k=t}a_k(t!){ k  \choose t} n^{k-t}$$
 de $s^{(t)}(0) =s^{t}(-1)  $ follow
$$ \sum^{p+1}_{k=t}a_k(t!){ k  \choose t} 0^{k-t} = \sum^{p+1}_{k=t}a_k(t!){ k  \choose t} (-1)^{k-t} \Rightarrow   $$
$$ a_t.t! = t!\sum^{p+1}_{k=t+2}a_k{ k  \choose t} (-1)^{k-t} + a_t(t!)-a_{t+1}(t+1)!  \Rightarrow$$
$$ a_{t+1} =\frac{1}{t+1}\sum^{p+1}_{k=t+2}a_k{ k  \choose t} (-1)^{k-t} $$
as we wanted to show.

**[2-Using Bernoulli numbers]**

$$ \sum^{n-1}_{k=0}k^p=\frac{1}{(p+1)}\sum^{p}_{k=0}{p+1 \choose k}B_k .n^{p-k+1}.$$

**[ Bernoulli Numbers]**

The Bernoulli numbers are defined by the generating function

$$\frac{x}{e^{x}-1} =\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}B_{n}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}$$
(we  will you use that definition)

**Proof:**

We define the function
$$f_n(x)=\frac{x(e^{nx}-1)}{e^x -1}. $$
We have $\sum\limits^{n-1}_{k=0}x^k=\frac{x^{n}-1}{x-1}$, so take $x=e^x$
it follows
$\sum\limits^{n-1}_{k=0}e^{xk}=\frac{e^{x.n}-1}{e^x-1}$
, then
$$f_n(x)=x\sum\limits^{n-1}_{k=0}e^{xk} $$
using the series
$e^z=\sum\limits^{\infty}_{t=0}\frac{z^t}{t!} $
taking $z=xk$ follows
$$e^{x.k}=\sum^{\infty}_{t=0}\frac{x^t.k^t}{t!} $$
replacing in $f_n(x)$ we have
$$f_n(x)=x \sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\sum^{\infty}_{t=0}\frac{x^t.k^t}{t!}= \sum^{\infty}_{t=0}(\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\frac{k^t}{t!})x^{t+1}$$
then the coefficient of $x^{p+1}$ is $\sum\limits^{n-1}_{k=0}\frac{k^p}{p!}.$

We have
$$f_n(x)=\frac{x(e^{nx}-1)}{e^x -1}=(\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{B_kx^k}{k!} ) (\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{x^k n^k}{k!} )=x(\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{B_kx^k}{k!} ) (\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{x^k n^{k+1}}{(k+1)!} )$$

The product of the last two series is
$\sum\limits^{\infty}_{k=0}c_k x^k $,
where $$c_p=\sum^{p}_{k=0}\frac{B_k .n^{p-k+1}}{k! (p-k+1)!} $$

is the  coefficient of $x^{p+1}$. Comparing with the coefficient of the other series
$$\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\frac{k^p}{p!}=\sum^{p}_{k=0}\frac{B_k .n^{p-k+1}}{k! (p-k+1)!} $$
follows
$$\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}k^p=\frac{1}{(p+1)}\sum^{p}_{k=0}\frac{B_k .n^{p-k+1}p!(p+1)}{k! (p-k+1)!}=\frac{1}{(p+1)}\sum^{p}_{k=0}{p+1 \choose k}B_k .n^{p-k+1}. $$

Then we have the result
$$ \sum^{n-1}_{k=0}k^p=\frac{1}{(p+1)}\sum^{p}_{k=0}{p+1 \choose k}B_k .n^{p-k+1}.$$

**Extra:\Edited:**

There are other ways to find.
**3-Using the euler maclaurin summation**
$$\sum f(x)=B_{0}\int f(x) +\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}B_{k+1}.\frac{D^{k}}{(k+1)!}f(x) +c$$
 $B_{k}$ here is also a bernoulli number.

**4- Using  the Worpitzky identity**
$$x^{n}=\sum^{n}_{k=0}\bigg<^{n}_{k} \bigg> {x+k\choose n} .$$
And the summation of binomials (it's easy to sum binomial)
here $\bigg<^{n}_{k} \bigg>$ are eulerian numbers

**5-Using Newton interpolation formula**

$$f(x+n)=\sum^{n}_{k=0}{n \choose k}\Delta^k f(x) $$
we can apply that to the sum direclty or in any term $x^k$ to write it as the sum of binomial coefficients. (in that way the stirling numbers of second kind appear)

Comment: Isn't this not a general formula though?

Comment: I think it's a general formula, but it's not "closed", to find the coefficients we need a recurrence relation in this aproach

Comment: Ah yes I see. I don't think it is in fact possible to get a closed formula no matter how complicated it is, because the coefficients have to be generated somehow. +1

Comment: Thanks!  : ) it's really not so easy to find the sum of powers in the "canonical form" $x^k$ (it's "easy" only to find the integral, derivative ).  With summation is more easy (or natural) to work with binomial coefficients (one way to find the sum of powers is to transform $x^k$ as a sum of binomial coefficients, which are easy to sum. 

But... ins this type of transformation the coefficients that arise are not simple either (stirling numbers of second kind, eulerian numbers etc).
obs: For the stirling numbers of second kind, if my memory don't betrayal me, there is a closed formula)

Answer (score 0):

*Too long for a comment.*

Concerning $$S_k=\sum _{i=1}^n (a+ (i-1)d)^k$$ the problem is still worse but, for given $k$, you can "easily" derive nice formulae
$$S_1= \left(a-\frac{d}{2}\right)n+\frac{d }{2}n^2$$
$$S_2= \left(a^2-a d+\frac{d^2}{6}\right)n+ \left(a d-\frac{d^2}{2}\right)n ^2+\frac{d^2
   }{3}n^3$$
$$S_3= \left(a^3-\frac{3 a^2 d}{2}+\frac{a d^2}{2}\right)n+\frac{1}{4} \left(6 a^2
   d-6 a d^2+d^3\right)n^2+ \left(a d^2-\frac{d^3}{2}\right)n^3+\frac{d^3
   }{4}n^4$$ and so on.

For sure, if $a=0$, these reduce to  Faulhaber's formulae (multiplied by $d^k$)